# How do I find the anomalous sub-population

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

Here's my problem: I basically have a collection of objects, think of them as a database table with multiple columns, something like:

- table name: "Persons"
- columns:

  - id
  - date inserted
  - age (1 for 0-9 years old, 2 for 10-19 years old, and so on),
  - face type (1 for round, 2 for oval etc),
  - hand size (1 for small, 2 for medium etc),
  - had chronic diseases (1 yes, 2 no),
  - had history of mental problems (1 yes, 2 no),

and other similar columns. There are ~30 columns total. Anomalous values can occur in any of them.

From time to time, anomalous rows get inserted into this database table, in bulk. For example, a whole sub-population, for example all persons with age 3 (30-39 years), inserted on aug 20th, have face type 95% just "1" (round), while the remaining 5% have other, normal, values.

My question is, how can I automatically detect and report such anomalous behavior? My constraint is that I cannot pre-validate the data in any way. I can only detect the event after it happened (think of the persons as visitors on a website, if it helps - I just record them and throw out the junk later). I do not expect an implementation, just somewhat detailed ideas. What kind of algorithms can I use? Artificial intelligence algorithms, genetic algorithms, something simpler (graphs)? How is this usually done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) on anomaly detection, as it presents quite a few ideas, for example looking for clusters.

Otherwise a simple method I can think of is first of all sorting the data by date and then by age, and then checking whether a specific trait occurs suspiciously often or seldom. Testing for anomaly **could** look something like this:

1. Get the ratio of the current trait
2. Check the ratio is sufficiently "out of bounds"

"out of bounds" could denote a specific distance from the norm:

```
function outOfBounds(trait, index)
  norm = 1 / number of distinct traits
  ratio = number of people with trait / total number of people
  return abs(norm - ratio) > ratio;
end function;
```